How can I disable the onClick event when the dropdown plaeholder is selected?
I've tried various ways to prevent the onClick event when either placeholder is selected but have been unable to get this to work. Here's what I have so far:
    <div class="choosesign">
  <div class="zodiacs">
    <select id="zodiac-me" class="zodiac-me" name="zodiac1">
        <option value="none">Your Sign</option>
        <option value="1">Aries</option>
        <option value="2">Aquarius</option>
        <option value="3">Cancer</option>
        <option value="4">Capricorn</option>
        <option value="5">Gemini</option>
        <option value="6">Leo</option>
        <option value="7">Libra</option>
        <option value="8">Pisces</option>
        <option value="9">Sagittarius</option>
        <option value="10">Scorpio</option>
        <option value="11">Taurus</option>
        <option value="12">Virgo</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="zodiacs">
    <select id="zodiac-them" class="zodiac-them" name="zodiac2">
        <option value="none">Their Sign</option>
        <option value="1">Aries</option>
        <option value="2">Aquarius</option>
        <option value="3">Cancer</option>
        <option value="4">Capricorn</option>
        <option value="5">Gemini</option>
        <option value="6">Leo</option>
        <option value="7">Libra</option>
        <option value="8">Pisces</option>
        <option value="9">Sagittarius</option>
        <option value="10">Scorpio</option>
        <option value="11">Taurus</option>
        <option value="12">Virgo</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="zodiacs" id="gobutton">
<a id="zodiacchoice" href="#" onclick='GotoLink()'> <h1>
  GO</h1> </a>
</div>
</div>

<script>function GotoLink(){
  var sel = $('.zodiac-me option:selected').text();
    var sel2 = $('.zodiac-them option:selected').text();
    if (sel=='Your Sign') {
    document.getElementById("zodiacchoice").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("zodiacchoice").href = '/' + sel + '/' + sel + '-vs-' + sel2;
  }
}</script>

I tried using the if statement to clarify, but the onClick isn't disabled. The link still works correctly.

You can use .val() to get selected value.
Attribute value in <option> is string, use sel === 'none'.
Use javascript:void(0) to disable the <a>


function GotoLink() {
  var sel = $('#zodiac-me').val();
  var sel2 = $('#zodiac-them').val();
  if (sel === 'none' || sel2 === 'none') {
    document.getElementById("zodiacchoice").href = 'javascript:void(0)';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("zodiacchoice").href = '/' + sel + '/' + sel + '-vs-' + sel2;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choosesign">
  <div class="zodiacs">
    <select id="zodiac-me" class="zodiac-me" name="zodiac1">
      <option value="none">Your Sign</option>
      <option value="Aries">Aries</option>
      <option value="Aquarius">Aquarius</option>
      <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
      <option value="Capricorn">Capricorn</option>
      <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
      <option value="Leo">Leo</option>
      <option value="Libra">Libra</option>
      <option value="Pisces">Pisces</option>
      <option value="Sagittarius">Sagittarius</option>
      <option value="Scorpio">Scorpio</option>
      <option value="Taurus">Taurus</option>
      <option value="Virgo">Virgo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="zodiacs">
    <select id="zodiac-them" class="zodiac-them" name="zodiac2">
      <option value="none">Their Sign</option>
      <option value="Aries">Aries</option>
      <option value="Aquarius">Aquarius</option>
      <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
      <option value="Capricorn">Capricorn</option>
      <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
      <option value="Leo">Leo</option>
      <option value="Libra">Libra</option>
      <option value="Pisces">Pisces</option>
      <option value="Sagittarius">Sagittarius</option>
      <option value="Scorpio">Scorpio</option>
      <option value="Taurus">Taurus</option>
      <option value="Virgo">Virgo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="zodiacs" id="gobutton">
    <a id="zodiacchoice" href="#" onclick='GotoLink()'>
      <h1>GO</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>



